# Which first: PHING or Jenkins? Deployment from GitHub

Tags: git, github, jenkins, phing

I plan on using Jenkins for CI, but I am just getting going with Git, PHPUnit and now PHING, as I need to deploy local server to development/testing server (using GitHub).

I know PHING can do this, and PHING integrates into Jenkins. My question is, should I get PHING going and then do Jenkins? Or would there be an advantage to getting Jenkins first, and then going to PHING?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jenkins needs a way to run your unit tests - so you need a build file in the first place (ant or phing). Without it, jenkins cannot build your project.